# How to fix NuGet error Version conflict detected for Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, stimulsoft

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1107  Version conflict detected for Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore. Install/reference Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore 2020.2.3 directly to project QRADARV12.Stimulsoft to resolve this issue. 
 QRADARV12.Stimulsoft -> Stimulsoft.Dashboards.Web.NetCore 2020.2.3 -> Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore (= 2020.2.3) 
 QRADARV12.Stimulsoft -> Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore 2019.3.4 -> Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore (= 2019.3.4). QRADARV12.Stimulsoft    D:\Q-RADARV12\General Version\UI\QRADARV12.Stimulsoft\QRADARV12.Stimulsoft.csproj   1
```

I keep getting this issue over and over, and i have no idea on how to fix this already.

Comment: What nuget pckage did you install to face this issue? Was `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore 2019.3.4` nuget package?

Comment: Or could you please share the nuget packages' names in your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to fix NuGet error Version conflict detected for
>   Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore

I think you have installed one of  `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore 2019.3.4` and `timulsoft.Dashboards.Web.NetCore 2020.2.3` nuget packages, then install the other and face the issue.

I have tested in my side and get the same error message:

[image]

The main reason is that they two nuget packages both have a dependency called `Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore`.

`Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore 2019.3.4` has the dependency `Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore 2019.3.4`

**while**

`timulsoft.Dashboards.Web.NetCore 2020.2.3` has the dependency `Stimulsoft.Reports.Engine.NetCore 2020.2.3`.

Different nuget packages all point to this dependency but different versions of the dependencies cause different versions of the dependencies, causing conflicts.

**Solution**

You should make sure that the two main nuget packages have the same version.

**----------**

**1)** If you first installed `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore 2019.3.4`, you should installed `timulsoft.Dashboards.Web.NetCore 2019.3.4`

**Or**

update `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore 2019.3.4` to **2020.2.3** and then installed `timulsoft.Dashboards.Web.NetCore 2020.2.3`

[image]

**----------**

**2)** If you installed `timulsoft.Dashboards.Web.NetCore 2020.2.3` first, you should then

installed `Stimulsoft.Reports.Web.NetCore 2020.2.3`.

Comment: hi ! thank you so much for your response, it worked well. thanks again for this detailed answer.